# If an updated object in S3 serves as a lambda trigger, is there an inherent race condition?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

If I update an object in an S3 Bucket, and trigger on that S3 PUT event as my Lambda trigger, is there a chance that the Lambda could operate on the older version of that object given S3’s eventual consistency model?

I’m having a devil of a time parsing out an authoritative answer either way...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a possibility that a blind `GET` of an object could fetch a former version.

There are at least two solutions that come to mind.

Weak: the [notification event data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/notification-content-structure.html) contains the etag of the newly-uploaded object.  If the object you fetch doesn't have this same etag in its response headers, then you know it isn't the intended object.

Strong: enable versioning on the bucket.  The event data then contains the object `versionId`.  When you download the object from S3, specify this exact version in the request.  The consistency model is not as well documented when you overwrite an object and then download it with a specific version-id, so it is possible that this might result in an occasional 404 -- in which case, you almost certainly just spared yourself from fetching the old object -- but you can at least be confident that S3 will never give you a version other than the one explicitly specified.

If you weren't already using versioning on the bucket, you'll want to consider whether to keep old versions around, or whether to create a lifecycle policy to purge them... but one brilliantly-engineered feature about versioning is that the parts of your code that were written without awareness of versioning should still function correctly with versioning enabled -- if you send non-versioning-aware requests to S3, it still does exactly the right thing... for example, if you delete an object without specifying a version-id and later try to `GET` the object without specifying a version-id, S3 will correctly respond with a 404, even though the "deleted" version is actually still in the bucket.

Comment: This is where I wish there was backoff-and-retry functionality within Lambda. "Wrong version? Go ahead and retry in another x seconds" style.

Comment: There is... throw a deliberate exception in your function and it should be retried twice more.  I know this works when you use S3 → SNS → Lambda, and the documentation seems to say that, since S3 fires functions asynchronously, they should be retried, too.
 http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invoking-lambda-function.html

Answer (score 1):

How does the file get there in the first place? I'm asking, because if you could reverse the order, it'd solve your issue as you put your file in s3 via a lambda that before overwriting the file, can first get the existing version from the bucket and do whatever you need.

Comment: The file in question is a long-running file where versioning doesn't make a lot of sense; think index.html as an example.

Comment: Not a thing-- you asked how the file gets there. "It's always been there" is the unfortunate answer!

Comment: I harden to believe you, because Amazon doesn't write random files in your buckets...