# AWS Lambda Trigger For Same S3 File Name In Quick Succession

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have AWS Lambda trigger configured on POST/PUT S3 event. S3 files are generated with same name with some variation in the content almost at the same time. The first file (file1.json) is generated with Content A and the second file with same name (file1.json) is generated with Content B. When these  two files are dropped almost at the same time, Lambda triggers twice however both trigger reads the latest Content. It looks like by the time Lambda is triggered first time, the latest Content is overridden and both triggers happens to read the latest Content.
Is it possible to have (by some configuration) the first trigger reads Content A and then second trigger reads Content B?

I tried to enable the versioning on the bucket which creates two version of same file however that is not helping

Comment: How did versioning not help? I'd expect the event sent to each Lambda function to indicate not only the bucket and key but also the version ID. Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44916630/if-an-updated-object-in-s3-serves-as-a-lambda-trigger-is-there-an-inherent-race).

Comment: In this case only versioning will help. The lambda will get time, versionId, key and size. From versionId you will easily get it.

Answer (score 0):

I found these 2 links:

- [S3 Versioning workflow](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/versioning-workflows.html)
- [How to access Versioned Objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/RetrievingObjectVersions.html)
- [Sample Event](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/blob/de51f6811a68226f2238b77fd74b84df29c446f4/events/testdata/s3-event.json#L32)

From what I gathered, from the event, you can get the `versionId` of the object and use AWS SDK to procure that specific version of the object. Then you can continue processing it as per your use case.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This will help. However I have got this issue in production and this requires the code change in the Lambda function. Is there any way to make this work without code change temporarily?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see any other way other than modifying the lambda code.